# Adding two ints not doing anything

Tags: minecraft, bukkit

So the problem is, when I say `ovrxp = ovrxp + xp`, it never stacks and just resets every kill. A fix to this and an explanation to why this doesn't work would be much appreciated.

```
@EventHandler
public void onDeath(EntityDeathEvent e) {

    Player player = (Player) e.getEntity().getKiller();
    Skeleton s = (Skeleton) e.getEntity();

    int ovrlvl = 1;
    int ovrxp = 0;

    Random random = new Random();
    int xp = random.nextInt(30) + 21;

    if (ovrlvl == 1 && ovrxp >= 200) {
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "You are now level two!");
        player.playSound(player.getLocation(), Sound.LEVEL_UP, 1.0F, 0.0F);
        ovrlvl = 2;
    }
    if (ovrlvl == 2 && ovrxp >= 400) {
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "You are now level three!");
        player.playSound(player.getLocation(), Sound.LEVEL_UP, 1.0F, 0.0F);
        ovrlvl = 3;
    }

    ovrxp = ovrxp + xp;

    if (s.getCustomName() == "Undead Recruit") {
        if (ovrlvl == 1) {
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "" + ovrxp + "/200");
        }
        if (ovrlvl == 2) {
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "" + ovrxp + "/400");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've declared `ovrxp` as a *local* variable - it's initialized each time `onDeath` is called.

If you want the value to persist between multiple calls to the method, you'll need to make the variable a field (part of the object itself). Assuming the method is always called on the same object, and on the same thread, just making it an instance field should be fine.